# Tensorflow 1 TFLite conversion from_session and from_frozen_graph produces wrong outputs

Tags: tensorflow-lite, tensorflow1.15

I converted a TensorFlow 1 model without Keras to TFLite using the following command:

```
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_session(sess, input_tensors=[my_input_tensor],
            output_tensors=[my_output_tensor])
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

The output is successfully saved, but when making predictions using the model, the output is completely different from the output of the regular TensorFlow model. Here is how I run inference in Python:

```
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

print("input details", input_details)
print("output details", output_details)

interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_array.reshape(input_shape))

interpreter.invoke()

output_buff = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index']).squeeze()
```

Console:

```
input details [{'name': 'input_batch', 'index': 0, 'shape': array([  1, 606, 414,   1], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([  1, 606, 414,   1], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
output details [{'name': 'Mul', 'index': 1, 'shape': array([  1, 505, 324,   1], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([  1, 505, 324,   1], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```

The output appears to be either a copy of the input signal or random noise.

I'd appreciate help in fixing this.

[Update]: I also tried the approach of freezing the graph first to a pb file, but got the same result.

Comment: Have you tried saved_model? Try [saved model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/saved_model/simple_save) and then [convert from saved model](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter#from_saved_model)